# how to configure intl in php.ini for symfony2

Tags: apache2.4, php-5.6, symfony-2.8

I configured my simfony 2.8.7. I used apache (httpd-2.4.20-win32-VC11) and php (php-5.6.23-Win32-VC11-x86). First of all. I uncomment in php.ini this line:

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

And the time zone like this:

```
date.timezone = "America/Lima"
```

After that I copied the icu dlls into the apache/bin folder and finally I created my project using netbeans 8.1 and I run it. But I have an error: 1.In most cases you should be fine, but please verify there is no inconsistencies between data provided by Symfony and the intl extension. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007 for an example of inconsistencies you might run into. Please what would be the solution?. Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you restart Apache after the copy of the `icu*` files

Comment: Yes. I also restarted the PC